# Page sequence number

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way in google analytics reports to check the sequence in which a user viewed.

Let says I have a website with 10 pages (Page1, Page2, .... Page10).

User1 sequence - Page1, Page3, Page5
User2 sequence - Page1, Page6, Page2

Comment: This isn't about programming so it's off topic, but you can try the Navigation Summary report which shows you something similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: For a single client id try the new user explorer report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual users can be viewed in this manner using the newly added 'Audience > User Explorer' feature.

For a more general look at how users flow through your website, you can either use the 'Audience > Users Flow' report (see what I did there?), which provides a visualization of common first steps into your website.

However, my favorite way to look at site flows is to go to 'Behavior > Site Content > 'All Pages', pick a page, and select 'Navigation Summary'.